# Correctly extend interface with generics

Tags: java, generics

I would like to correctly extend an interface but since is uses generics, I became a bit confused.
Here is the first interface

```
public interface A<T extends Resource>{
 ...
}
```

I would like to write something like this but it does not work.

```
public interface B<T extends Resource> extends A<T extends Resource> 
{
 ...
}
```

I do not understand why this does not work.
Could you explain?

Comment: I would try `public interface B<T extends Resource> extends A<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have already defined the type `T`, it should be:

```
public interface B<T extends Resource> extends A<T> {

}
```